# Kill the context of an AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Lambda function that I need to kill its context when it has a specific error, as that error when invoked again will make the Lambda function not work properly if the context is the same as the last invocation.

From what I had understood if I throw a new `RuntimeException` it should kill the context but it is not doing that.

Any idea how could I kill the context from inside my code?

```
public class IncorrectFileExtensionException 
  extends RuntimeException {
    public IncorrectFileExtensionException(String errorMessage, Throwable err) {
        super(errorMessage, err);
    }
}
```

I know the Lambda function context is not getting destroyed/killed because after I throw that custom runtime exception the next time I invoke it it uses the same context, I can confirm this as its using the same CloudWatch log stream and its no longer doing a cold boot.

What I need to achieve is for the Lambda function's context of that invocation to get killed and for it to start the next time in a cold boot.

Comment: It seems to me that "a lambda" lasts as long as there are references to it (just like anything else in Java).  So, how are you retaining references?  If the context has changed, it's not the same lambda.

Comment: Why do you say that it is not 'killing' the context? Please edit your question to show us how you have come to this conclusion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have now edited the question to add more details

Comment: @iggy in aws im not sure, as what I need to achieve is that after I throw that runtime exception it starts the next time from a cold boot

Comment: I just realised this question was about some AWS service rather than the Java concept of 'lambda expression' - I don't have anything to say about AWS, sorry.

Comment: No problem, thank you very much @iggy

Comment: AWS Lambda functions intentionally re-use the container for fast execution. This can be useful because the container already exists and global variables can be retained through multiple executions, allowing for faster startup. I don't think it is possible to 'force' a container to be deleted. See: [AWS Lambda execution environment - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html)

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way - *why* can't you reuse the container?  What in your code "breaks" the Lambda container such that it needs to be completely restarted?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes that is correct, its just that I would think there would be a way to force a container to be deleted, like if you throw some kind of exception it will be deleted

Comment: @stdunbar the problem is that im also using an AWS HSM so when i log in if that step fails the when i try again in the next execution it will fail, so I am pretty much forced to kill the container as to avoid any kind of error in the next execution
I have some retry logic and catch for the exceptions, but as per aws support not all of them can be handled so it would be best to just kill the container and start fresh

Comment: @PabloArriola what? just try the login inside your handler and not outside, so you shouldn't have this problem

Comment: @eis I understand but its faster if I could just kill the environment, its not the most elegant way but it would be faster as this is a time sensitive lambda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't manually kill an execution environment (lambda instance) either via console/api or from within your function.

Throwing an exception from within your code (or passing an error in to callback(e)) will merely produce an invocation error that gets logged and reported in cloudwatch. There is no way to throw a "fatal" error, AWS doesn't differentiate your functions errors for you. The same execution environment will get reused until it has been idle for some non deterministic period of time or aws decides to terminate it for some other reason. This is true for function timeouts as well.

*So your main concern should be making sure that errors cannot put your function code in to a non recoverable state.* Lambda invocations are intended to be idempotent at least in the sense that the result of the function should never depend on the state of the execution environment.

That said, there are some tricks you can use when things go haywire.

1. throttling.  you can reduce reserved concurrency of your function to zero, which will cause aws not to deliver new invocations to any of your current execution environments. side effect being of course that your lambda function is inaccessible, so doing this in production is very taboo. but eventually unthrottling should cause new execution environments to be created. this is particularly useful when your lambda is in a fail/retry loop for an event a bug is preventing it from processing.
2. if you're invoking a particular function alias, you can publish a new version of your function and move the alias to point to the new version. execution environments are unique to a function version. this can have unintended side effects if there are already newer versions than the problematic one since lambda versioning is linear and can't be branched.
3. if you're effectively invoking $LATEST, either via an alias or by not specifying version/alias, any change to lambda code or configuration (environment variables, memory limit, timeout, etc) will cause all current execution environments to receive no new requests.

The obvious problem with 2 and 3 is that in real environments under load, this results in massive cold start penalties as there are suddenly no warm execution environments to handle requests.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes its something that we normally do, but in this case as the lambda is time sensitive it would be faster to just kill that specific environment instead of handling the logic inside of it.

Really appreciate your response

Comment: Option #3 works flawlessly with the combination of EventBridge scheduler and I think I will use as a temporary workaround before I find the original issue.
Thank you!